# c++ string function

Tags: c++, linux

i am trying to create a string function which is callable from the main function, however this gives segmentation fault... any ideas???

also is it possible to create a string function which returns a string..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

string callMe(string& k){

    cout << "String from callMe: " << k;

}


int main(){

   string k;

   k = "K SHK";

   cout << "String from main function: " << k << endl;

   callMe(k);

}
```

**UPDATE:**

its compiles fine..

```
[root@server dev]# ./stringtest 
String from main function: K SHK
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: No reason for SEGFAULT in this code. Can you post the error, please?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Which compiler do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared your function as returning a `string`, but don't return one.

There are two ways to fix it:

- If you didn't intend to return a string, change `callMe` to

  `void callMe(string& k);`
- If you did intend to return a string, then do so, by adding a return statement, e.g.

  `return "I'm returned from callMe, called with " + k;`

Additionally, some style comments:

- It is a good idea to initialize variables right at the point of definitions where possible. In your case you'd write:

  ```
  string k = "K SHK";
  ```

  or

  ```
  string k("K SHK");
  ```

  If you don't intend to modify the string afterwards, you might also consider to define is as `const` to catch accidental changes (e.g. by use of `=` instead of `==`):

  ```
  string const k = "K SHK";
  ```
- If you don't change the argument in `callMe`, you should use a reference to const:

  ```
  void callMe(string const& k);
  ```

  resp.

  ```
  string callMe(string const& k);
  ```

This will allow you to call the function on constant strings and string literals, like `callme("I'm a string literal");`

Comment: @GGG what "same deal with `main`"?

Comment: @GGG: No. First, `main` *must* return `int`, so changing to `void` is no option, and second, there's a special rule for `main` in C++ that reaching the end of `main` without a `return` is equivalent to `return 0;` so an explicit `return` is *not* necessary in this case (but still may be considered good style).

Comment: @celtschk huh, I could have sworn I used to be able to write `void main`, but now g++ yells at me. Didn't know about the special rule either, thanks.

Comment: @GGG: Some compilers accept `void main` as non-standard extension; and infamously Microsoft's compiler once even suggested to change to `void` in a warning if you omitted a `return` in `main` (I don't know if it still does).

Answer (score 7):

your function `callMe` is expected to return a string, but you never return anything.

If you have compiler warnings enabled, you are warned about this ( i suggest adding -Wall and -Wextra)

It's resolvable be changing the return type from `string` to `void`.

The `main` function however does not need a return statement (but for beginners it may be better to just add `return 0;`):

From the C++ standard:

> A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage
>   duration) and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. **If control reaches the end of main without
>   encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing "return 0;"**

Answer (score 1):

```
void callMe(string& k){

    cout << "String from callMe: " << k;

}
```

Since you have declared Callme as a function that returns string, and on other side you are returning just nothing,such code can cause segmentation fault.(Since value in eax is undefined).

Comment: @Papergay :- string callMe(`string& k`) ,you think will it make sense for return k;

Answer (score 0):

callMe() and main() functions must return something...

Comment: in C++, main does not need to expicitely return a value. If the programmer does not provide anything, it falls back to the default value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `callMe` there is no `return`. Try:

```
void callMe(string& k)
{
   cout << "String from callMe: " << k;
}
```

The `main()` function must return an `int` (usually 0).

Ps: If you don't modify the string k in your function, use a const reference `const string&`.

Answer (score 0):

> also is it possible to create a string function which returns a string..
>   Certainly.  With a slight modification from your original code above it would look something like this...

```
string callMe(string& k){
    string returnValue("String from callMe: ");
    returnValue += k;
    cout << returnValue << endl;
    return returnValue;
}
```